# How to get the NPP Instance inside a NPAPI C plugin

Tags: c, plugins, npapi

I have written a NPAPI plugin in C which needs to call the  [NPN_Invoke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_Invoke)  function 
(in order to call a JavaScript function).

But NPN_Invoke() takes the [NPP](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NPP) instance as a parameter.

Only the NP_New() and NP_Destroy() functions get passed NPP instance. How do I get this NPP instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NP_GetEntryPoints define your own NP_yourNew Function, Now when the after the NP_New the framework calls your NP_yourNew with the instance. The instance could be saved when the your callback just gets invoked.

Comment: You can find good examples of this in the mozilla codebase, under: mozilla-central/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/npruntime. You could also check out the FireBreath project (http://www.firebreath.org) for an example of a fully-implemented plugin framework. Start in np_winmain.cpp in one of the example projects and look at the src/NpapiPlugin project

Answer (score 2):

The best way is actually to extend NPObject with a field to save the associated NPP instance, and provide the allocate/deallocate functions with your NPClass definition.  You can then cast the NPObject to your subtype to access the actual NPP instance.

I would *NOT* recommend doing this at a global level (NP_GetEntryPoints, etc.) as suggested above, as there are potentially several instances of your plugin loaded - maybe even on the same page - and you want to be sure you're invoking the correct one.  Unfortunately there seems to be a lot of sample code out there where some random instance is just kept in a global variable, and updated as much as possible.

As an example, assuming C++, you'll want to extend NPObject:

```
struct MyNPObject : public NPObject {
  NPP npp_;
  explicit MyNPObject(NPP npp) : npp_(npp) {}
};
```

Then your NPClass definition will need to have allocate and deallocate definitions:

```
static NPClass obj_Class = {
  NP_CLASS_STRUCT_VERSION,
  &obj_allocate,
  &obj_deallocate,
  NULL,
  &obj_hasMethod,
  &obj_invoke,
  ...
```

Which could be implemented like so:

```
static NPObject* obj_allocate(NPP npp, NPClass *aClass)
{
  return new MyNPObject(npp);
}

static void obj_deallocate(NPObject *obj)
{
  delete obj;
}
```

And when you need to call NP_Invoke, assuming you have the NPObject* (inside obj_invoke, for example) you just downcast:

```
MyNPObject* myObj = reinterpret_cast<MyNPObject*>(obj);
g_browser->invoke(myObj->npp, ...)
```